# Makefile examples for Haskell tasks

Tags: haskell, makefile, cabal, quickcheck, hlint

Rather than invent my own, what are good makefile rules for typical Haskell tasks such as compiling, packaging, hlint, quickcheck, etc?

In a search I find things like [like this example](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/5.00/building/sec-makefile-arch.html):

```
ghc -M *.hs
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Forget make; just use [`cabal-install`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-install).

Comment: also see: [How to write a Haskell program](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/How_to_write_a_Haskell_program)

Comment: In the examples shown for both cabal-install and "how to..." `runhaskell Setup build` and `cabal haddock`.  Does anyone use Make to orchestrate the use of cabal?

Comment: @haroldcarr Just running `cabal install` will do both of those if you turn `documentation: True` in `~/.cabal/config`.

Comment: Seems I should read the doc carefully.  Will it do `hlint` too?

Comment: @haroldcarr You can set up a test suite and run it with `cabal test`.

Comment: Great.  So now what would useful is to see some example cabal config files that are used in production code.  Thanks, H

Comment: @haroldcarr I tend to run hlint through a .ghci file, as described [here](http://neilmitchell.blogspot.co.uk/2010/01/using-ghci-files-to-run-projects.html).

Comment: @haroldcarr Just take a look at the cabal files of the most depended on libraries (say _text_, _unordered-containers_, _snap_ etc). These are all used in production in various situations, should be representative. Especially for the test/benchmark bits of the cabal file. 

And yes, cabal is pretty much the basis for the tasks you mentionned in your question.